# Regex Hero results differ from vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

Hi I am using Regex Hero to make a Regex. It worked as expected in Regex Hero. I then transferred it over to vb.net and now I get different results from the same exact data. I don't get it!

The Regex:

```
  \d{10,13}.+?(?=(\bF\b|\bT\b|\bCT\b))
```

The .net code:

```
 Dim strRegex As String = "\d{10,13}.+?(?=(\bF\b|\bT\b|\bCT\b))"
    Dim myRegex As New Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None)

    Dim strTargetString As String = a

    For Each myMatch As Match In myRegex.Matches(strTargetString)
        If myMatch.Success Then
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(myMatch.Value & Environment.NewLine)
        End If
    Next
```

The Data:

```
"   The Meijer Team appreciates your business                   12/26/14     Your fast and friendly checkout was             provided by ALARIA       MEIJER SAVINGS     SPECIALS                       4.77     COUPONS                       20.00 SAVINGS TOTAL   24.77     YOUR TOTAL SAVINGS              SINCE 01/01/14       1,814.62     For additional savings and rewards visit                 mPerks.com   GENERAL MERCHANDISE 7569107330    DYNO GEL THIMBL     1.49  CT 7569100487    DYNO THIMBLES       3.49  CT   DRUGSTORE 2220094152    DEODORANT           1.99   T 30041667803   TOOTHBRUSH          9.99   T *70882049496  ORBIT TOOTHB      was      3.69       now      2.95   T *1700006806   ANTIPERSPIRANT      1  @ 2 / 6.00      was      3.99       now      3.00   T   GROCERY 6414404213    CHEF BOYARDEE      2  @  1.07                   2.14  F 6414404306    CHEF BOYARDEE       1.07  F 6414404315    CHEF BOYARDEE       1.07  F 6414404322    CHEF BOYARDEE       1.07  F 7680828008    SPAGHETTI      2  @  1.34                   2.68  F 5100002549    PASTA SAUCE      2  @  1.97                   3.94  F 4335400750    TORTILLAS           1.99  F 4400000057    SALTINES            2.69  F 4400002854    NABISCO OREOS      2  @  2.98                   5.96  F 1312000484    FROZEN FRIES        2.99  F 4125002562    CHEESE SLICES       2.99  F 4125010210    MEIJER MILK      2  @  3.09                   6.18  F 5150092751    PANCAKE SYRUP       3.19  F 3000032188    OATMEAL             3.29  F 3000032189    OATMEAL             3.29  F 8390000649    GOLD PEAK TEA       3.29  F 71373336283   MEIJER MILK         3.29  F 4400002734    COOKIES             3.49  F 1410007083    PEPPERDIGE FARM      2  @  3.99                   7.98  F 1600027297    CEREAL              4.19  F 1600043471    CEREAL              4.19  F 4850001833    ORANGE JUICE        5.69  F 1450001420    BIRDS EYE VOILA     7.39  F *4400003113   SNACK CRACKER      was      2.77       now      1.99  F *5100002526   SPAGHETTIOS      3  @ 5 / 5.00      was      3.27       now      3.00  F *7192176312   FROZEN PIZZA      2  @  5.49      was     12.58       now     10.98  F *7131400331   AUNT MILLIE"S      1  @ 2 / 6.00      was      3.39       now      3.00  F    Total Basket Coupon      => 20.00 off               -20.00               Mperks # -- ********** TOTAL              MI 6% Sales Tax      1.16              TOTAL TAX            1.16              TOTAL              107.09 PAYMENTS  Primary Account -   Debit   ATM/DEBIT CARD       TENDER   107.09 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX                NUMBER OF ITEMS         42       See meijer.com or the Service Desk for            current return policy.     For additional savings and rewards visit                 mPerks.com.     Tx:XXX  Op:XXXXXX Tm:XX  St:XX   XXXXXXXXXXX       How are we doing? Rate your shopping experience and you may win $1000 in Meijer gift cards!  Visit us at www.meijer.com/tellmeijer or call 1-800-394-7198  Secure Code: 7800-0601-5020-3373-001  Survey should be completed within 72 hrs  "
```

Comment: How is it different exactly?

Comment: It doesn't match things like "1700006806 ANTIPERSPIRANT 1 @ 2 / 6.00 was 3.99 now 3.00" type records but does match "7569100487 DYNO THIMBLES 3.49" records.

Where as in regex Hero and Regex Storm it does match those.

Comment: I'm seeing it match both of those examples. Have you messed something up in your tests/checks to do with the lookahead, i.e. the last part of that regex: `(?=(\bF\b|\bT\b|\bCT\b))`? So for example, the pattern will not match "7569100487 DYNO THIMBLES 3.49" but DOES match "7569100487 DYNO THIMBLES 3.49 CT"

Comment: Okay you got me thinking and rather than pulling the data from the PDF I just used the copied string as the a variable. In that case everything worked as expected. So maybe the output from getting the PDF has some kind of hidden characters that are messing it up? How do I remove those? I'm using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor

Comment: ok I got it, it was .Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "") to remove those chars.